# How to loop through the specified clip in ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

## Environment

Android is greater than or equal to API 19
ExoPlayer 2.7.1

## Needs

Loop a specified segment of a local video ( for example, loop the 3rd to 11th seconds of the video )

## Tried

I try to use the `seekTo` method, and I can really achieve the goal. However, there was an obvious pause ( about several hundred milliseconds or more ) when calling the `seekTo` method.

But if the entire video was played in a loop using `LoopingMediaSource`, there would be no sense of pause. Therefore, if I want to play a segment of the video in a loop instead of the entire video, is there any way to connect without a sense of pause like' LoopingMediaSource'?